# How to disable one of multiple gesture recognizers?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to disable 1 of 3 gesture recognizers I have added to a view, does anyone know what the correct code is?

Here's what i have so far:

```
// the gesture recognizer i'm trying to disable

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    myImageView1.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


// the code to disable it

    let allGRs = [currentView.gestureRecognizers]

    for g in allGRs {

        if let g as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
            g.isEnabled = false
        }

    }
```

Thankyou!

Comment: Sounds like you should assess why your adding gestures that you later need to disable? Maybe you need to set one gesture more important than another by using the method required(toFail: )

Comment: @SeanLintern88 this worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the name property to your gesture recognizer.

`tap.name = "myTapGesture"`

And later you can cycle through the recozniers and only disable the one that you want.

```
for aRecognizer in view.gestureRecognizers {
   if let name = aRecognizer.name {
       if name == "myTapGesture" {
           aRecognizer.isEnabled = false
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you!

1. Add unique name to your `UITapGestureRecogniser`

   ```
   let tapName = "100" //Any unique name
   func addGestureRecognisers() {
       let view = UIView() // Your view in your context. I just added to test my code
       let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
       tap.name = tapName 
       view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   }
   ```
2. Filter `UITapGestureRecognisers` and then Filter the result by `name`.

   ```
   func disableTapGesture(from view: UIView) {
       view.gestureRecognizers?.filter({$0.name == tapName}).first?.isEnabled = false
   }
   ```